# Capture Desktop Screen QT/C++ WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, screen-capture

I'm using QT/C++ and I would like to capture the screen of my desktop and get the pixels buffer.

I'm using this function but it returns weird pixels values, can someone tell me why ?

```
void CaptureScreen()
{
int nScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
int nScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(hDesktopWnd);
HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight);
SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap);

BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, nScreenWidth, nScreenHeight, hDesktopDC, 0,0, SRCCOPY|CAPTUREBLT);

BITMAPINFO bmi = {0};
bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmi.bmiHeader);
bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = nScreenWidth;
bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = nScreenHeight;
bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

unsigned char *pPixels = new unsigned char[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight * 4];

GetDIBits(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap, 0, nScreenHeight, pPixels, &bmi,    DIB_RGB_COLORS);

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    qDebug() << (int) pPixels[i];
}

delete[] pPixels;

ReleaseDC(hDesktopWnd, hDesktopDC);
DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
DeleteObject(hCaptureBitmap);
}
```

Output is 1 1 1 255 1 1 1 255 ... but first pixels on the top of screen I have is white. It should be 255 255 255 255 etc...

Thank you !

Comment: `A bottom-up DIB is specified by setting the height to a positive number, while a top-down DIB is specified by setting the height to a negative number.` - so you have bottom-up DIB and begin dump from bottom line

Comment: Thank you. It means that pPixels[0] = pixel on x(1920) & y(1080) ?

Comment: yes, the first line is bottom. if want another order use `bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -nScreenHeight;`

Comment: Why you don't just call `GetDC(NULL)` instead of `HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow(); HDC hDesktopDC = GetDC(hDesktopWnd);`?

Comment: Thank you! I didn't notice.
@zett42 should I? I saw this method to retrieve desktop window.. I just used it.

Comment: *"It means that pPixels[0] = pixel on x(1920) & y(1080) ?"* - No. Assuming your display is 1920x1080 pixels, `pPixels[0]` is the **first** pixel of the final scanline. In other words: x = 0; y = 1079.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved!
Thanks to RbMm comment :

```
A bottom-up DIB is specified by setting the height to a positive number, while a top-down DIB is specified by setting the height to a negative number.

the first line is bottom. if want another order use bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -nScreenHeight;
```

I just replaced this line `bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = nScreenHeight;` by this `bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = - nScreenHeight;` and I get pixels from top line.
It can help someone else :)